# How can I show more than 100 results per page?

Tags: web-scraping

I want to change the number of results on this page: `https://fifatracker.net/players/` to more than 100 and then export the table to Excel and make it much easier for me. I tried to scrape it using python following a tutorial but I can't make it work. If there is a way to extract the table from all the pages it would also help me.

Comment: Their API request allows max 100, any bigger number and it defaults back to 50. But you can make same requests with increasing page size, don't need scraper for that, simple code can do it, check network tab when changing page size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, it's restricted to 100 per request. Simply iterate through the query payload on the api to get each page:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://fifatracker.net/api/v1/players/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}

page= 1 
payload = {
    "pagination":{
        "per_page":"100","page":page},
           "filters":{
               "attackingworkrate":[],
               "defensiveworkrate":[],
               "primarypositions":[],
               "otherpositions":[],
               "nationality":[],
               "order_by":"-overallrating"},
           "context":{
               "username":"guest",
               "slot":"1","season":1},
           "currency":"eur"}

jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()
current_page = jsonData['pagination']['current_page']
last_page = jsonData['pagination']['last_page']

dfs = []
for page in range(1,last_page+1):
    if page == 1:
        pass
        
    else:
        payload['pagination']['page'] = page
        jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()
        
    players = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['result'])
    dfs.append(players)
    print('Page %s of %s' %(page,last_page))

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                     slug  ... info.contract.loanedto_clubname
0            lionel-messi  ...                             NaN
1       cristiano-ronaldo  ...                             NaN
2      robert-lewandowski  ...                             NaN
3               neymar-jr  ...                             NaN
4         kevin-de-bruyne  ...                             NaN
                  ...  ...                             ...
19137           levi-kaye  ...                             NaN
19138      phillip-cancar  ...                             NaN
19139         julio-pérez  ...                             NaN
19140     alan-mclaughlin  ...                             NaN
19141   tatsuki-yoshitomi  ...                             NaN

[19142 rows x 92 columns]
```